# Add multiple items to a asp repeater using tuples

Tags: c#, asp.net, tuples, asprepeater

I've created a repeater on the front end, and I need to add multiple items, the second item is a string and this needs to be added to the image src, any thoughts?

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="WeatherForcastWeek" >
  <ItemTemplate>
     <td>
       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Day1" />
       <asp:Image runat="server" ID="WeatherIcon" />
       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Min" />
       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Max" />
     </td>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Below is the DataSource type

```
Tuple<string, string, double, double>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use ImageUrl property and pass the value using the item binding syntax for ASP.NET WebForms <%# Item.Property #>

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="WeatherForcastWeek" ItemType="System.Tuple`4    [System.String,System.String,System.Double,System.Double]">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <td>
       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Day1" Text="<%# Item.Item1 %>" />
       <asp:Image runat="server" ID="WeatherIcon" ImageUrl="<%# Item.Item2 %>" />
       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Min" Text="<%# Item.Item3 %>"/>
       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Max" Text="<%# Item.Item4 %>"/>
     </td>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Fernando! this solved my issue, I had a feeling it had something to do with code blocks, Kudos!